# Horse riding books in German

Tags: germany, language

Is there a book that I can use to learn all the needed German vocabulary related to horse riding?

When I was in UK there were a lot of books to prepare for the examinations (like Stage 1, Stage 2 etc). And those I found really good, because they were giving you all the knowledge about:

- horse anatomy
- different food types
- explanations on bits
- saddle parts nomenclature
- horse training tips
- stable management

and so on. Is there anything similar in German language? Because I am at the point where I have the knowledge (learned in UK on the aformentioned books) but I do not know how to say it in German, plus I would like to learn what is the German "way" on the same topics.

I went to a library and looked for books, but they are really a soft introduction to the horse riding world and I want something more technical and specific.

Comment: I'm pretty sure standard literature has been translated, not rewritten. If you had a good book, look up it's translation into German.

Comment: A good place to get started might be to look up the various terms in Wikipedia in English, then switch to the German versions of those articles and see what words they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advices in the comments I started a new research and finally found something interesting: the **Deutsche Reiterliche Vereinigung** (official german horse riding society) website [link](https://www.pferd-aktuell.de/).
There you can find all information (in german) that you need for your training (Ausbildung) as a rider and much more.
There is also an official book called **Die Reitabzeichen 5-1** [book link](https://www.pferd-aktuell.de/fn/newsticker/fnverlag/neu-im-fnverlag-die-reitabzeichen-5-1-) which gives exactly the information I was looking for. Other suggested books you can find on the website.